# Gazebo plugin-Failed to resolve RegisterPlugin error+ Gazebo topic visualization

Tags: ros, gazebo-plugin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

BH

I'm trying to attach a plugin to a launch file. When launching the file, I keep getting this error: Error [Plugin.hh:158] Failed to resolve RegisterPlugin: /home/hayim/buildworldtutorial/build/libwall1world.so: undefined symbol: RegisterPlugin[ INFO] [1431075019.325996696]: Starting plugin Kobuki(ns = //)!

Must mention,The plugin is attached according to the [Overview of Gazebo Plugins tutorial] while the names are changed and also the helloworld.cc file.

Generally, the code should move the turtlebot forward and I wish to see that in gazebo.

By the way, how come I can't see the cmd_vel_mux topic by picking the topic visualization tab on Gazebo?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208848/gazebo-plugin-failed-to-resolve-registerplugin-error+-gazebo-topic-visualization/) by [Haz88](https://answers.ros.org/users/22113/haz88/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2015-05-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem, which in my case was caused by forgetting to include the macro
"GZ_REGISTER_MODEL_PLUGIN(MyPlugin)"
in the gazebo namespace.

---

Originally posted by [dudds4](https://answers.ros.org/users/26855/dudds4/) with karma: 26 on 2016-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1